# cannot access the files in my express route

Tags: node.js, file, mammoth

I'm trying to do the following:

upload a doc file to the a specific express route, 
and then use mammoth to parse it to an html object,

this is the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth

My problem is that it takes the file in the documentation straight from the route, which is not what I want,
I want to upload a file to my route and parse it...

```
router.post("/parseCV", (req, res) => {
  console.log("entered route");
  console.log(req.files);
});
```

Im uploading the file like that :

```
 const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    uploadImage(formData);
  };
```

how can I access it in my route ?
req.files,req.body are all undefined

Comment: Are you using `multer` to access files?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) module which let you deal with multipart request.

Example:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: '/temp/uploads/' }); // Destination of where you wanna upload your file

router.post("/parseCV", upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log("entered route");
    console.log(req.file); // Contains the path of your file.
    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO WITH YOUR FILE
});
```